# Best way to execute a method unordered with different parameters over many threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have a large list of numbers (4,718,515 of them) and I need to run a method with each of them.
I have a method `Check(number)` that needs to be ran with the items in `numbers`.

I don't know the most efficient way to go about this in c#

Here are some examples of how I was able to do it in other languages if it helps

python:

`pool.imap_unordered`

and in Java:

```
forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(processes);
            forkJoinPool.submit(() -> words.stream()
                .unordered()
                .parallel()
                .filter(CheckValidity::checkValidity)
```

Comment: Does running `Check(number)` on one number affect running it on any other number?  Can you run them completely in parallel, not caring about ordering?  If so, take a look at `Parallel.ForEach`.  It will do a fairly good job of partitioning work over the set of threadpool threads.  In my experience, it does a great job of parallelizing CPU-bound, independent work.  By the way, I'm no Java expert, but you have unbalanced parens in your Java code

Comment: @Flydog57 yeah there was a bit more code in the Java code but it was unnecessary to the question so I cut it out. Check(number) doesn't affect any other number so I will make sure to check out `Parallel.ForEach()`

Comment: You might want to add a bit of C# code to your question, showing, for example, the type of `numbers`.  Perhaps something like `IEnumerable<int> numbers = Get4MillionNumbers(); numbers.DoInParallelSomehow(number => Check(number));` and explain what it means

Comment: Since you likely did a lot of research (like reading similar questions https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+run+code+parallel+site%3astackoverflow.com) please [edit] the question to demonstrate result of that research. This will help to narrow down advices as obviously you've already tried standard `Parallel.*` and `Task.WhenAll` approaches and those did not lead to acceptable results.

Comment: Unless each call to `Check(number)` is expensive then it doesn't help greatly to use threads. And if the call is expensive then `4,718,515` numbers might still take a long time.  If each call takes a second you might reduce the time from 55 days to about 7.

Comment: Given the little we know now, here's how I would do it with Microsoft's Reactive Framework: `IObservable<int> query = from n in numbers.ToObservable() from c in Observable.Start(() => Check(n)) where c select n;  int[] checks = await query.ToArray();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(numbers, number => Check(number));
```

The [Parallel.ForEach method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) attempts to run the `Check` operations in parallel using multiple threads.

Comment: I recommend specifying explicitly the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to a reasonable value (like `Environment.ProcessorCount`) when using the `Parallel` class. Its default value is `-1`, which means unbounded parallelism. This causes the `ThreadPool` to become immediately saturated, and to stay saturated until the source enumerable completes.

Comment: Is that true?  The few times I've used Parallel.ForEach (never setting `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`), I've seen it run N threads on a N logical core system. The time I remember most the app was doing mostly CPU-bound work on a 4-core box that took from about 1-5 seconds for each item.  We logged starts and stops.  It was fun to watch it start 1-4, finish 3, start 5, finish 2, start 6, finish 3, start 7, and so on

Comment: From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism _"Generally, you do not need to modify this setting."_.  It does say this: _"If it is -1, there is no limit on the number of concurrently running operations."_, but it doesn't say it will saturate the thread pool, it says it will use _"the thread pool's heuristics ... to determine the right number of threads to use"_.  In my experience, the default behavior works pretty well.

Comment: @Flydog57 it works pretty well, provided that your program is doing nothing else during the parallel execution. If you have also some `System.Timers.Timer` ticking, or some asynchronous method on the fly composed internally by multiple `await` points, the saturated `ThreadPool` will cause hiccups and delays to all asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: @Flydog57 take a look for example at [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BYG5yc) fiddle. A `Parallel` loop is started with 102 elements, with each one requiring 2 seconds of processing time. The `ThreadPool` is given 100 initial threads. The `Parallel.ForEach` immediately starts processing the first 101 elements (100 `ThreadPool` + 1 current thread), but the element #102 cannot be started because the `ThreadPool` is now saturated. A new thread is injected one second later, for a total processing time of 3 seconds. The commented PLINQ version has a different default (`Environment.ProcessorCount`).

Comment: @Flydog57 regarding the documentation, I find this particular page misleading. The `Parallel` class has an unfortunate default, that cannot be fixed because of backward compatibility considerations, and the docs should warn the programmers about it instead of pretending that everything is OK. I provided feedback to this page a week ago, but I don't think that this is the way to have it fixed. Maybe someone should open a issue on GitHub. Btw the upcoming in .NET 6 [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1946) will probably have `Environment.ProcessorCount` as default.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: That's surprising.  That example I gave above is real.  There were about 35 units of work.  On a 4 core machine, I could see four threads start immediately and then new work start up as each thread finished its previous work.  The prod boxes were 8-core.  I did not normally do full logging in prod, but out of curiosity I changed the config one day to see how it behaved.  I saw 8 slices of work get dispatched, and then new ones on each completion of a previous unit of work.  Hmmmm

Answer (score 0):

In C# there is [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) library

```cs
var desiredResult = numbers
   .AsParallel()
   .AsUnordered()
   .Where(number => Check(number))
   .ToArray();
```